# Reading Serial Number from AT24CS32

Tags: c, embedded, i2c, microchip

I'm building an embedded system using a Microchip dsPIC33EP hooked up to an AT24CS32.  I'm trying and failing to read the serial number from the AT24.  My board has the SOT23 package part on it, so [A2:A0] are tied to ground and are logic 0.  According to section 6.1 of the [datasheet](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/aemDocuments/documents/OTH/ProductDocuments/DataSheets/20006341A.pdf) I should use device address `0x58` to read the serial number.  Whenever I use this address in a dummy write to set the eeprom address, I get a NACK in code and on my logic analyzer.

Here is the datasheet example for the serial number read dummy write:
[image]

Here is a logic analyzer trace where I try to write the serial number read address:
[image]

Here is the same code writing to set up a read of the main memory area:
[image]

I can successfully read and write to the main eeprom memory area uisng device address 0x50 with the same code.

To try and debug this I've also tried writing the desired serial number memory address (0x0800) to the main device type identifier address.  The dummy write succeeds, but I always receive `0xFF` from the data read.  This makes sense to me since 0x0800 is in the valid range for the main eeprom array.

For reference, here is the code I'm using to setup the serial number read:

```
I2C1_MESSAGE_STATUS status;
// Serial number 7-bit device type identifier: 0b1011xxx
uint8_t ser_addr = 0x58;
// Word address specified in table 6-2
uint8_t addr_buf[2] = {0x08, 0x00};
I2C1_MasterWrite(addr_buf, 2, ser_addr, &status);
while (status == I2C1_MESSAGE_PENDING) {
    __delay32(9000);
}
   
// Only ever see I2C1_DATA_NO_ACK here, never see the address word make it to the wire
if(status != I2C1_MESSAGE_COMPLETE) {
    return false;
}
```

My question is, can anybody see something I'm doing wrong when trying to read the serial number from this part?  I think I must be misinterpreting something about the datasheet, but my logic analyzer trace looks the same as the datasheet example as far as I can tell.

Comment: The LA trace looks fine so far, beside the fact of NAK. The data sheet mentions acknowledge polling in chapter 7.3, did you take this into account? Did you respect all other timings requirements, do you use an I²C hardware module or do you bit bang?

Comment: I haven't fully implemented ACK polling yet, but I have tried adding manual delays and having all other i2c access shut off during debugging.  Will look further into timing requirements, but since the main array reads and writes are working I figured the timing is fine.  I'm using the PIC I2C hardware module.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the clarifications there for the next visitors. We do not expect such in comments, this is not a forum. ;-)

Comment: You shouldn't need to fiddle with I2C timing adjustments if the EEPROM side of the chip works. It may be incorrect documentation or a faulty chip.